# Ninject interception attribute with parameters passed to interceptor?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject, ninject-interception

I have interception working currently (very simplistically) with the following code:

(see question at bottom)

My Interceptor:

```
public interface IAuthorizationInterceptor : IInterceptor { }
public class AuthorizationInterceptor : IAuthorizationInterceptor
{


    public IParameter[] AttributeParameters { get; private set; }


    // This doesnt work currently... paramters has no values
    public AuthorizationInterceptor(IParameter[] parameters) {
        AttributeParameters = parameters;
    }

    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation) {
        // I have also tried to get the attributes like this
        // which also returns nothing.
        var attr = invocation.Request.Method.GetCustomAttributes(true);


        try {
            BeforeInvoke(invocation);
        } catch (AccessViolationException ex) {

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw;
        }
        // Continue method and/or processing additional attributes
        invocation.Proceed();
        AfterInvoke(invocation);
    }


    protected void BeforeInvoke(IInvocation invocation) {

        // Enumerate parameters of method call
        foreach (var arg in invocation.Request.Arguments) {
            // Just a test to see if I can get arguments
        }

        //TODO: Replace with call to auth system code.
        bool isAuthorized = true;

        if (isAuthorized == true) {
            // Do stuff               
        }
        else {
            throw new AccessViolationException("Failed");
        }             
    }

    protected  void AfterInvoke(IInvocation invocation) {


    }
}
```

My Attribute:

```
public class AuthorizeAttribute : InterceptAttribute
{
    public string[] AttributeParameters { get; private set; }

    public AuthorizeAttribute(params string[] parameters) {
        AttributeParameters = parameters;
    }

    public override IInterceptor CreateInterceptor(IProxyRequest request) {
        var param = new List<Parameter>();
        foreach(string p in AttributeParameters) {
            param.Add( new Parameter(p, p, false));
        }
        // Here I have tried passing ConstructorArgument(s) but the result
        // in the inteceptor constructor is the same. 
        return request.Context.Kernel.Get<IAuthorizationInterceptor>(param.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Applied to a method:

```
[Authorize("test")]
public virtual Result<Vault> Vault(DateTime date, bool LiveMode = true, int? SnapshotId = null)
{
        ...
}
```

This works, and I am able to pass additional parameters through the attribute like this:

```
[Authorize("test")]
```

If you'll noticed in my attribute I am grabbing some parameters from the attribute, which I am able to access in the attribute class, but I am unable to pass those to the Interceptor. I have tried using the ConstructorArgument in the Kernel.Get<>() call, which doesnt throw an error, but the AuthorizationInterceptor constructor doesnt get any values from ninject. I have also tried GetCustomAttributes() as you can see in the code sample but this also returns nothing. From looking at other similar posts like this ([Ninject Interception 3.0 Interface proxy by method attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13494767/ninject-interception-3-0-interface-proxy-by-method-attributes?rq=1)) that seems to be the correct way, but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Constructor Argument should work. How about using ctor(IEnumerable<string> parameters) and Kernel.Get<IAuth..Interceptor>(new ConstructorArgument("parameters", (IEnumerable<string>)AttributeParameters); ? The ctor-parameter name and ConstructorArgument.Name must match!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get something working by creating an initialization method on the interceptor. I don't really like it, because it ties me to the specific implementation of AuthorizationInterceptor, but it gets the job done (damn deadlines lol). I would still like to know if there is a better way to do this, so I am not going to mark my own answer in hopes that somebody comes along with a better way of doing this.

I modified the attribute as follows:

```
    public override IInterceptor CreateInterceptor(IProxyRequest request) {
        AuthorizationInterceptor attr = (AuthorizationInterceptor)request.Context.Kernel.Get<IAuthorizationInterceptor>();
        attr.Init(AttributeParameters);
        return attr;
    }
```

And created an Init method on the the interceptor:

```
    public void Init(params string[] parameters) {
        AttributeParameters = parameters;
    }
```